# Select the UITableViewCell over the UITextView losing ability to call didSelectRowAtIndexPath Delegate Method?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uitextview

I am having an issue with my `UITableViewCell` selection.I am using a  `UITableViewCell` with a `UITextView` sub view. The `UITextView` object  is not editable, not scrollable, with user interaction enabled.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {      
        cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"DemoCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];         
        cell. accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
      if([distanceArray count]){ 
        UILabel *label1=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:1];      
        label1.text=[locationNameArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];
        label1.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        UILabel *label2=(UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];        
        [label2 setText:[distanceArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];
        UITextView *tview=(UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:3];   
        [tview setText:[discriptionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];         
        return cell;
      }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    DetailedLocationVIew *dView=[[DetailedLocationVIew alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailedLocationVIew" bundle:nil];       
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dView animated:YES];
    [dView release];
}
```

If i  select the cell over the `UITextView`, the delegate `didSelectRowIndexPath` not calling. Apart from over `UITextView`  object and selection works fine?
Why Selection Not working Over UITextView?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `tview.userInteractionEnabled=NO;` and It will solve your problem.

If this doesn't solve your problem then try this out

```
for(UIView * cellSubviews in cell.subviews)
{
    cellSubviews.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

It loops for all the subviews within cell and sets `userInteractionEnabled` property to `NO`.

Comment: I tried   userInteractionEnabled=NO and userInteractionEnabled=YES ,then also  not working

Answer (score 8):

These suggestions were not working for me in iOS 6.  What did work is the following.

In your:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Add this:

```
cell.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
cell.textView.editable = NO;
cell.textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(forwardToDidSelect:)];
cell.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.textView addGestureRecognizer: tap];
```

Along with:

```
- (void) forwardToDidSelect: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) tap
{
    [self tableView: self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: tap.view.tag inSection: kTextViewCellSection]];
}
```

It appears to be necessary to set userInteractionEnabled = YES after setting editable = NO.  Setting these in the XIB did not seem to work.

Comment: This is the right way to do it without compromises.

Answer (score 3):

Because the UITextView did catch the touch event, you can solve this in 2 ways:

1) Subclass UITextView, catch touch events then pass it to the superView's same method using:
ex:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
[self.superview touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

2) Using UITextView delegate:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
NSIndexPath *a = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:[textView tag]];
[tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
}
```

Comment: why UITableViewController touchesBegan method not calling

Comment: i am trying First one , becoz TextView Editable property disabled

Comment: Why do you use UITextView but disable it while you still can display multiple text in a label?

Answer (score 2):

If only one subview needs to be disabled, one can do the following in Swift.

```
theSubTextView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

This also disables isEditable and isSelectable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am resizing the `tableViewCell` depending on the `textView.text` length, so I've added a `UIView` on top of the `textView` and set its colour to `0.1%white`.